# HIVE, How to get an element from an array, the element itself is an array too

Tags: json, oracle, hadoop, hive

I have a database table that has one column storing JSON format strings.  The string itself contains multuple elements like an array.  Each element contains multiple key-value pairs.  Some value may also contain multiple key-value pairs as well, for example, the "address" attribute below.

```
People table:
  Col1      Col2   .....   info
  aaa       bbb           see below
```

For the column "info", it contains the following JSON format string:

```
 [{"name":"abc", 
  "address":{"street":"str1", "city":"c1"},
  "phone":"1234567"
 },
 {"name":"def", 
  "address":{"street":"str2", "city":"c1", "county":"ct"},
  "phone":"7145895"
 }
]
```

I need to get the single value of each field within the JSON string.  I am able to do that for all fields except the "address" field by calling the explode() as shown below:

```
 SELECT  
   get_json_object(person, '$.name') AS name,
   get_json_object(person, '$.phone') AS phone,
   get_json_object(person, '$.address') AS addr
 FROM people lateral view explode(split(regexp_replace(
      regexp_replace(info, '\\}\\,\\{', '\\}\\\\n\\{' ), '\\[|\\]',''), '\\\\n')) 
      p as person;
```

My question is how I get each field within the "address" field.  The "address" field can contain any number of key-value pairs and I can't use JSONSerDe.  I am thinking to use another explode() call, but I can't get it to work.  Can someone please help.  Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the json_objects directly with

```
SELECT  
  get_json_object(person, '$.name') AS name,
  get_json_object(person, '$.phone') AS phone,
  get_json_object(person, '$.address.street') AS street,
  get_json_object(person, '$.address.city') AS city,
  get_json_object(person, '$.address.county') AS county,      
FROM people lateral view explode(split(regexp_replace(
  regexp_replace(info, '\\}\\,\\{', '\\}\\\\n\\{' ), '\\[|\\]',''), '\\\\n')) 
  p as person;
```